# Atributo não é reconhecido, mas o Namespace está adicionado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, web-service, atributos

Meu atributo `[DataContract]` não está sendo reconhecido, mas o *namespace* `System.Runtime.Serialization` está adicionado em meu `using`.

Alguém sabe o porque?

```
....
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace SuporteTecnicoContracts
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    [Table(Name="T_PDV")]
    class T_PDV
    {
        public int IDPdv { get; set; }
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }
        public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
        public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
        public string Endereco { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string Complemento { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Cidade { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public string CEP { get; set; }
        public int DDD { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DDDCelular { get; set; }
        public string Celular { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int QtdeCheckOuts { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IDTipoRede { get; set; }
        public string NomeRede { get; set; }
        public int IDTipoEstabelecimento { get; set; }
        public string EnderecoIPInstalacao { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataAlteracao { get; set; }
        public string CaminhoLogo { get; set; }
        public string TokenAuthentication { get; set; }
        public string Distrito { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Latitude { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Longitude { get; set; }
        public bool IS_Ativo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ID_Rede { get; set; }
    }
```

....

Comment: Pode postar um exemplo de código?

Comment: Adicione a solução encontrada como resposta e marque como correta ou exlcua a pergunta, para que ela saia da fila de perguntas sem resposta

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque não se trata de uma pergunta necessitando resposta. Foi um erro que o próprio usuário solucionou e não pode mais ser reproduzido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenho 4 projetos em minha solution. Adicionei a dll da Serialization, mas não adicionei no projeto em questão. Não entendi porque não deu erro no using, sem a DLL. Mas adicionei e funcionou. Faltou atenção minha, reconheço meu erro.